# Contribute to hadoop by adding new jsp page with more grapical details about node performance

Tags: hadoop

I need to add a new jsp file to display different data and contribute to hadoop by adding this page. I added the jsp under job and once I build it, it generated the servlet and relevant tags in /job/META-INF/web.config. Since job runs on port 50030 (I can access task tracker on this port) I should be able to access this page on this port. But I can't access the page. Can you please tell me how can I add a new page to hadoop as a contributor.

Answer (score 0):

For any hadoop changes improvements, bugs, new feature to hadoop, first you got to propose this feature in hadoop developers community. This can be achieved by either raising a bug in apache Jira(different for 4 modules hdfs,mapreduce,yarn,common) in your case it is mapreduce so the url `https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE`  can be used (Need to create an account for raising issues)

or send out a mail to apache mapreduce developers mailing list `mapreduce-dev@hadoop.apache.org`. Based on the discussion, you can submit your code changes as a patch file